# Android: compile error Util.toByteArray (taken from an example)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compilation

I am trying to compile this sample of code in my Android app to have crypt/decrypt feature. I found that code here http://apachejava.blogspot.it/2012/04/androidencryption-made-easy.html I don't know if it's good but that's not relevant here.

When compiling it's all OK but `Util.toByteArray` produces this error "Util cannot be resolved". Replacing Util with Utils is not any useful.

Any help?

Comment: the link (the source of the code) seems to have broken over the years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the needed code is missing in the page you link : the author forgot to show his `Util` class which obviously contains a toByteArray `function`.

**Solution 1 : use commons IO**

Replace

```
Util.toByteArray(cis);
```

by

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(cis);
```

IOUtils is a [Apache commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) utility class.

You'll need

- to download the commons IO jar (see link) and set your classpath accordingly
- this import at the start of your class : `import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;`

**Solution 2 : write a toByteArray function**

Define this function :

```
public byte[] toByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int l;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    while ((l = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
      buffer.write(data, 0, l);
    }
    buffer.flush();
    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

And replace `Util.toByteArray(cis);` by `toByteArray(cis);`.

Comment: thx @dystroy but I get "the import ... cannot be resolved". How to include it in the project?

Comment: See edited answer. Choose the solution you prefer. The second one would of course be easier if you don't need other Apache utilities.