# Android equivalent for org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray

Tags: java, android, apache, arrays, encryption

I need to call the "toByteArray" method on a CipherInputStream variable, or use an utility class. Which is the Android code to do so?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Also: Maybe you should take a look at the source code of the IOUtils class?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540018/android-compile-error-util-tobytearray-taken-from-an-example

Answer (score 0):

Try [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). I haven't tested it but seems like it has what you need. toByteArray is listed in [their IO tools](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IOExplained).