# Getting the hash value of String

Tags: java, hash, sha1

I am having the following code to get the hash value of *String*:

```
package encryption;
import java.security.MessageDigest; 
public class MessageDigestExample {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        String input = "This is a message";
        MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        System.out.println("input : " + input);
        hash.update(Utils.toByteArray(input));
        System.out.println("digest : " + Utils.toHex(hash.digest()));
        } }
```

I am getting this exception at the moment:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Utils cannot be resolved
    Utils cannot be resolved
```

I added apache-storm-1.2.2 lib, but does not work,

Any help, please!

Comment: Just for the record, as new users sometimes forget about that: please consider accepting an answer at some point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: compile error Util.toByteArray (taken from an example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540018/android-compile-error-util-tobytearray-taken-from-an-example)

Answer (score 3):

You are using the (class?) name `Utils`, without ever importing it.

You probably lack some `import what.ever.Utils` statement here.

Beyond that, you get a runtime exception because you try to *run* code that did **not** compile. Although some IDEs, like eclipse, allow for that, it is in generally a bad idea, especially when you are a newbie to Java. You should always fix **all** compiler errors before you try to *run* a class.

Comment: @nana Sorry, but this isn't as easy at it seems. The other answer already gave you the exact syntax you need. Honestly: when you don't understand how to import a class, and how to fix all compiler errors prior running code ... then whatever you are trying to achieve here has to wait! These are really basic problems, and the only way is to follow a good book/tutorial, to learn step by step.

Answer (score 1):

You should import the Utils library you are using. If I am reading it correctly, add the following line underneath the package section:

import org.apache.storm.utils.Utils;

This should resolve the library Utils for you

Comment: Is this Utils-library on your classpath? Have you already used it for anything else?

Comment: @nana It can't be the *same* error. If you add that import statement ... the next thing is that the compiler can't **find** that class. This means that your classpath setup is missing that class. Subtle details matter here.

Comment: I got: import org.apache.storm.utils.Utils; Cannot be resolved.

Comment: @nana have you downloaded apache storm and added it to your classpath?

Comment: @nana - on the other hand, you don't really need it - you could write your own `toByteArray` as outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540189/2513200

Comment: @nana what IDE are you using and how are you trying to run your application?

Comment: I am using Eclipse.

Comment: There are 4 types of apache-storm:
•tar.gz
•zip 
•src.tar.gz
•src.zip
Can you please tell me which one to use?

Comment: @nana the zip version is probably easiest to use if you are developing on Windows

Comment: I did as you told me to do, still I got this exception !

Comment: @nana does this problem still exist?